# What is wrong with using sending intent to another Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle

I what to send a bundle with an `ArrayList`, but my code causes a `NullPointerException`. But I don't know why.

Main Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act1);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    txtName = findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtDepartment = findViewById(R.id.department);
    txtUndergred = findViewById(R.id.undergred);
    txtUrl = findViewById(R.id.url);
    txtPhone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
    btnphone = findViewById(R.id.btnphone);
    btnlogin = findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
    btnweb = findViewById(R.id.btnweb);

    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = txtName.getText().toString();
            String department = txtDepartment.getText().toString();
            String undergrad = txtUndergred.getText().toString();
            Bundle Sender = new Bundle();
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(name);
            list.add(department);
            list.add(undergred);
            Sender.putStringArrayList("list", list);
            ArrayList shit = Sender.getStringArrayList("list");
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("Sender", Sender);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

MainActivity2(receive here)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act2);
        txtUrl = findViewById(R.id.url);
        txtPhoneNum = findViewById(R.id.phoneNum);
        button0 = findViewById(R.id.goback);
        Intent passedIntent = getIntent();
        if (passedIntent != null) {
            Bundle mybundle = passedIntent.getBundleExtra("Sender");
            ArrayList list = mybundle.getStringArrayList("Sender");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Student info: "
                    +list.get(0)+list.get(1)+list.get(2),duration).show();
        }
        String Url = txtUrl.getText().toString();
        String PhoneNum = txtPhoneNum.getText().toString();
}
```

Here, which part is wrong? `Arraylist` is added to the bundle but every time a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

Comment: `Sender.putStringArrayList("list",list);` and `mybundle.getStringArrayList("Sender");` are using different keys. Use the same key.

Comment: Please visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) @klego99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The issue

---

You are passing a key and then trying to get the value with another key. This is wrong. To clear your understanding, let me give you an example →

Case: You have many tee-shirts in your shop. You ordered some tee-shirts to sale and got `red` and `green` tee-shirts only. Now, when a custom comes and he asks `yellow` tee-shirts, then you say that it is not there. That is called `null` in coding terms. This is the same case with you over here. Let's check the solution.

### The solution

---

When you send a value with a key, receive it with same key. Just try this code.

##### MainActivity 2

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act2);
        txtUrl=findViewById(R.id.url);
        txtPhoneNum=findViewById(R.id.phoneNum);
        button0=findViewById(R.id.goback);
        Intent passedIntent= getIntent();
        if(passedIntent != null){
            Bundle mybundle= passedIntent.getBundleExtra("Sender");
            ArrayList list= mybundle.getStringArrayList("list");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Student info: "
                    +list.get(0)+list.get(1)+list.get(2),duration).show();
        }
        String Url=txtUrl.getText().toString();
        String PhoneNum=txtPhoneNum.getText().toString();
```

### The not related but helpful thing

---

Do *not* try to see the values in toast. I see that here:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Student info: "
                    +list.get(0)+list.get(1)+list.get(2),duration).show();
```

Try to debug or display it in log instead.